# Error in merge function "Erreur de géotraitement GEOS: la différence a échoué"

Tags: qgis, mergeshapes

I am trying to merge three large shapefiles. After cleaning all the inconsistencies and artefacts, the merging of file 1 and 2 ends well, yet with the following message (sorry to be in French):

> L'entité n'a pas pu être écrite
>   suroutput_126be82a_bc81_4c47_908a_c1c95da91787
>
> Résultats: {'OUTPUT': 'output_126be82a_bc81_4c47_908a_c1c95da91787'}

I don't think it is a big problem.

But then, when I try to merge the 3rd file, the same error pops up and the algorithm stops with the following error:

> Erreur de géotraitement GEOS: la différence a échoué.

and no more details are given.

Comment: The entity could not be written. GEOS geoprocessing error: the difference failed. Maybe check the geometry for each of the three files?

Comment: I have done that
and all seems to be okay

Comment: Have a look at this bug report and see if it clarifies anything for you: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21349

Comment: I have already used the "fix geometries" as suggested in that bug. Still the same error. as a note, this only happens when I try to merge the third layer

Comment: I have found that this type of exercise works much better in grass.  I then export to postgis (using postgis dump format) to edit attributes, then export to shapefile if I need it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know (yet?) how to work with GRASS

Comment: I'd expect you would learn how to do this in grass faster than you would solve the problems you are encountering.  You can use v.overlay in the processing toolbox, the help file is here: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.overlay.html.  Use a buffer with an offset of zero first to sort out most topological issues.